# Good example of Rails testing with assertions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

What is a good example of an open source rails app (not gem, generator, etc) with a good test suite in minitest (with assertions), following good practices?

Comment: Please make this a community wiki

Comment: hmm.. check out https://github.com/redmine/redmine/tree/master/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the good open source rails app that used minitest with assertion and also followed good practices.

[Chiliproject](https://github.com/chiliproject/chiliproject)

[rstat.us](https://github.com/hotsh/rstat.us)

[sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

Hope it helps you.